# Fluentbit rewrite_tag not working with JSON Array

Tags: fluent-bit

We are using fluent-bit plugin to tail from a file and send to an HTTP endpoint.

The sample log looks like the following.

```
tenant 1 testing 100
```

The configuration for input looks like the following.

```
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/input/**/*.log
    Tag tenant
    Path_Key filename
```

We then use a lua filter to add a key based on the filepath. This works as expected.

```
[FILTER]
    Name  lua
    Match  *
    script  /etc/td-agent-bit/test.lua
    call  extract_id
```

At this point, we try to filter the message and rewrite the tag based on the tenantid.

```
[FILTER]
    Name          rewrite_tag
    Match         *
    Rule          $tenantid ^([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$ from.$tenantid false
    Emitter_Name  re_emitted
```

With a stdout, like below,

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name   stdout
    Match  *
```

we verified the message to be like the following.

```
tenant: [1630073320.394812583, {"log"=>"tenant 1 testing 100", "tenantid"=>"tenant1", "filename"=>"/var/log/input/tenant1/file1.log"}]
```

It looks like the rewrite_tag plugin is not able to work and change the tag as expected. Is there a problem with the regex pattern ? Any help on this will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your regex needs a very slight tweak to remove the dash in the match pattern. At the moment, it's looking for abc-123, but your tenant id format is abc123.

By removing the dash from your regex, the example tenantid field should match:

`^([a-z]+)-([0-9]+)$` will match "tenant-1"

`^([a-z]+)([0-9]+)$` will match "tenant1"